# MVC action in ASP .NET throws 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to add a delete method to an existing application designed with ASP .NET, the thing is that I have 0 experience with. Here is what I've done :

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost, Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult TypeLotRemove(Guid id)
{
    TypeLot typeLot = _repository.GetTypeLot(id);

    //On supprime le type de lot à la base.
    _repository.RemoveTypeLot(typeLot);
    return RedirectToAction("TypeLot");
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
public TypeLot RemoveTypeLot(TypeLot typeLot)
{
    _entities.RemoveToTypeLot(typeLot);
    _entities.SaveChanges();
    return typeLot;
}
```

**Designer.cs**

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
public void RemoveToTypeLot(TypeLot typeLot)
{
    base.DeleteObject(typeLot);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Supprimer","TypeLotRemove", new { id = item.ID} )%>
```

When I click on the link, I'm redirected to `TypeLotRemove/420c039f-516e-40c5-916f-6da222eb50ae` so I have a 404 error (normal cause I don't have TypeLotRemove file) and nothing is done. What did I missed ?

Comment: change the tag to mvc

Comment: Change `post` for `get` in method TypeLotRemove

Comment: 1 does not look like a Guid...

Comment: `Html.ActionLink` will render an anchor tag that is normally a GET request. You decorated  your action method `TypeLotRemove` as `HttpPost`

Comment: @anmarti Thanks that's solved the problem

Comment: @mstaessen Yes sorry, it was just for the exemple but I edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are just generating a link to the `ActionMethod`, when you have decorated the `ActionMethod` with the `[HttpPost]` verb. This means that this `ActionMethod` is only accessible via a `POST` request.

Using `[HttpPost]` makes sense in this case so just do this in your View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("TypeLotRemove", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)
{
   // Your form and submit
}
```

Also pointed out by mstaessen in the comments you are attempting to access the URL `/TypeLotRemove/1` again this is a `GET` request but the parameter you are passing (in this case `1`) is not a `GUID` that you require in your `ActionMethod`

Comment: Thanks, `HttpGet` solved the problem. As I said in comment `1` was just for the example, I've edited my question.

Comment: I think using a `HttpPost` is the correct solution for your example. otherwise people can just go to the browser and request /TypeLotRemove/GUID and delete things. (I know they could also with POST but add in an anti forgery token and it does make it a bit more secure).

Answer (score 1):

Change `HttPost` for `HttpGet`in method TypeLotRemove